# col2im implementation in ConvNet

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution

I'm trying to implement a **CNN** only using numpy.

While doing the backpropagation, I found out that I had to use **col2im** in order to reshape **dx**, so I checked the implementation from https://github.com/huyouare/CS231n/blob/master/assignment2/cs231n/im2col.py.

```
import numpy as np


def get_im2col_indices(x_shape, field_height, field_width, padding=1, stride=1):
  # First figure out what the size of the output should be
  N, C, H, W = x_shape
  assert (H + 2 * padding - field_height) % stride == 0
  assert (W + 2 * padding - field_height) % stride == 0
  out_height = (H + 2 * padding - field_height) / stride + 1
  out_width = (W + 2 * padding - field_width) / stride + 1

  i0 = np.repeat(np.arange(field_height), field_width)
  i0 = np.tile(i0, C)
  i1 = stride * np.repeat(np.arange(out_height), out_width)
  j0 = np.tile(np.arange(field_width), field_height * C)
  j1 = stride * np.tile(np.arange(out_width), out_height)
  i = i0.reshape(-1, 1) + i1.reshape(1, -1)
  j = j0.reshape(-1, 1) + j1.reshape(1, -1)

  k = np.repeat(np.arange(C), field_height * field_width).reshape(-1, 1)

  return (k, i, j)


def im2col_indices(x, field_height, field_width, padding=1, stride=1):
  """ An implementation of im2col based on some fancy indexing """
  # Zero-pad the input
  p = padding
  x_padded = np.pad(x, ((0, 0), (0, 0), (p, p), (p, p)), mode='constant')

  k, i, j = get_im2col_indices(x.shape, field_height, field_width, padding,
                               stride)

  cols = x_padded[:, k, i, j]
  C = x.shape[1]
  cols = cols.transpose(1, 2, 0).reshape(field_height * field_width * C, -1)
  return cols


def col2im_indices(cols, x_shape, field_height=3, field_width=3, padding=1,
                   stride=1):
  """ An implementation of col2im based on fancy indexing and np.add.at """
  N, C, H, W = x_shape
  H_padded, W_padded = H + 2 * padding, W + 2 * padding
  x_padded = np.zeros((N, C, H_padded, W_padded), dtype=cols.dtype)
  k, i, j = get_im2col_indices(x_shape, field_height, field_width, padding,
                               stride)
  cols_reshaped = cols.reshape(C * field_height * field_width, -1, N)
  cols_reshaped = cols_reshaped.transpose(2, 0, 1)
  np.add.at(x_padded, (slice(None), k, i, j), cols_reshaped)
  if padding == 0:
    return x_padded
  return x_padded[:, :, padding:-padding, padding:-padding]

pass
```

I expected when I put **X** into **im2col_indices**, and putting that output back to **col2im_indices** will return the same **X**, but it didn't.

I don't understand what col2im actually does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm right, the output is not the same X because each cell of X is converted to multiple `col`s, and it's been multiplied during `im2col_indices`.

Say you have a simple image `X` like this

```
 1 2 3
 4 5 6
 7 8 9
```

and you convert it with kernel size 3, stride 1, and the `same` padding, the result would be

```
0 0 0 0 1 2 0 4 5
0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
0 0 0 2 3 0 5 6 0
0 1 2 0 4 5 0 7 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
2 3 0 5 6 0 8 9 0
0 4 5 0 7 8 0 0 0
4 5 6 7 8 9 0 0 0
5 6 0 8 9 0 0 0 0
* *   * *
```

as you can see, the first cell with value 1 shows up in four `col`s: 0, 1, 3, 4.

`im2col_indices` first zero initialize a image with padded size, and then add each `col` to it. Focus on the first cell, the process should be like

1.zero initialized image

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

2.add `col 0`

```
0 0 0 0 0     0 0 0 - -     0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0     0 1 2 - -     0 1 2 0 0
0 0 0 0 0  +  0 4 5 - -  =  0 4 5 0 0
0 0 0 0 0     - - - - -     0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0     - - - - -     0 0 0 0 0
```

3.add `col 1`

```
0 0 0 0 0     - 0 0 0 -     0  0  0  0  0
0 1 2 0 0     - 1 2 3 -     0  2  4  3  0
0 4 5 0 0  +  - 4 5 6 -  =  0  8 10  6  0
0 0 0 0 0     - - - - -     0  0  0  0  0
0 0 0 0 0     - - - - -     0  0  0  0  0
```

4.add `col 3`

```
0  0  0  0  0     - - - - -     0  0  0  0  0
0  2  4  3  0     0 1 2 - -     0  3  6  3  0
0  8 10  6  0  +  0 4 5 - -  =  0 12 15  6  0
0  0  0  0  0     0 7 8 - -     0  7  8  0  0 
0  0  0  0  0     - - - - -     0  0  0  0  0
```

5.add `col 4`

```
0  0  0  0  0     - - - - -     0  0  0  0  0
0  3  6  3  0     - 1 2 3 -     0  4  8  6  0
0 12 15  6  0  +  - 4 5 6 -  =  0 16 20 12  0
0  7  8  0  0     - 7 8 9 -     0 14 16  9  0
0  0  0  0  0     - - - - -     0  0  0  0  0
```

The first cell is multiplied by 4 when converted back. For this simple image, `col2im_indices(im2col_indices(X))` should give you

```
 4  12  12
24  45  36
28  48  36
```

Comparing to the original image, the four corner cells `1 3 7 9` are multiplied by 4, the four edge cells `2 4 6 8` are multiplied by 6 and the center cell `5` is multiplied by 9.

For large images, most of the cells will be multiplied by 9 and I think it roughly means your learning rate is actually 9 times larger than you think.

Comment: Okay, now I understand how col2im_indices work, and why col2im_indices(im2col_indices(X)) don't give you X back. But why is it done like that? I thought in the backward pass, we calculate dx_col(col vector of dx), and change it back into dx with col2im, so shouldn't col2im just undo what im2col did? Am I understanding something wrong in the backward pass part?

Comment: IMHO, you're right. col2im should undo what im2col did. However, the code you post is from cs231n assignment and I think it's just much easier to implement like that. I don't know how this will affect the convergence, but as I know no better than people who wrote this so I think it's at least ok for some "from scratch" projects.

Answer (score 1):

Replying this 2 years old thread, it may help someone in future.

Here is my understanding. In the CNN back propagation context, col2im matrix is the product of filters and back propagated error(dout). It must be noted the matrix is already a product of two matrices, unlike in im2col use case in the forward pass where we have just stretched the input into im2col matrix ready for multiplication(convolution). Due to this difference between im2col and col2im, in col2im we need to add back propagated error to all the contributing input indices.

Let us consider an example of 1x5x5 input, single 1x3x3 filter, 0 padding, stride 1. The indices of the input will look like:

```
[0,0] [0,1] [0,2] [0,3] [0,4]
[1,0] [1,1] [1,2] [1,3] [1,4]
[2,0] [2,1] [2,2] [2,3] [2,4]
[3,0] [3,1] [3,2] [3,3] [3,4]
[4,0] [4,1] [4,2] [4,3] [4,4]
```

The resulting 9x9 im2col indices computed for the forward propagation
matrix multiplication will look like:

im2col indices

```
<-----------------------  9 ----------------------------->
[ 0] [0,0] [0,1] [0,2] [1,0] [1,1] [1,2] [2,0] [2,1] [2,2] 
[ 1] [0,1] [0,2] [0,3] [1,1] [1,2] [1,3] [2,1] [2,2] [2,3] 
[ 2] [0,2] [0,3] [0,4] [1,2] [1,3] [1,4] [2,2] [2,3] [2,4] 
[ 3] [1,0] [1,1] [1,2] [2,0] [2,1] [2,2] [3,0] [3,1] [3,2] 
[ 4] [1,1] [1,2] [1,3] [2,1] [2,2] [2,3] [3,1] [3,2] [3,3] 
[ 5] [1,2] [1,3] [1,4] [2,2] [2,3] [2,4] [3,2] [3,3] [3,4] 
[ 6] [2,0] [2,1] [2,2] [3,0] [3,1] [3,2] [4,0] [4,1] [4,2] 
[ 7] [2,1] [2,2] [2,3] [3,1] [3,2] [3,3] [4,1] [4,2] [4,3] 
[ 8] [2,2] [2,3] [2,4] [3,2] [3,3] [3,4] [4,2] [4,3] [4,4]
```

In the backward pass when we generate col2im matrix by multiplying back propagated error dout and the filter the resulting indices which appears like above is already the result of multiplication. When we convert this back to the input error we need to add corresponding indices in a given location in the input error array.

For example:

```
input_error[0,0] = im2col_error[0,0]
input_error[0,1] = im2col_error[0,1] + im2col_error[1,0]
input_error[0,2] = im2col_error[0,2] + im2col_error[1,1] + im2col_error[2,0]
....
....
```

This is evident from the indices matrix above.